# Backup software for Ubuntu with GUI

Tags: ubuntu, backup

I am looking for backup software for ubuntu desktop with below ability:

- Should have GUI
- Having ability to restore single file from Backup
- Password Encryption
- Ability to backup on G-drive dropbox
- Should have Free of cost

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

i think Bacula is best choise for you

https://www.bacula.org/

*Backport code from BEE

*New Qt-Based Tray Monitor

*Maximum Concurrent Jobs for Devices

*Allow Compression and Accurate Backup

*Accurate File set Options

*Tab-completion for Console

*ACL Updates and Extended Attributes

*Virtual Backup and Duplicate Job Control

*TLS Authenticatio